# How do I change postfix configuration after installing it?

Tags: postfix

During the postfix installation and configuration, I was presented with a few options on how to send and receive email.  I might have chosen the wrong option.  How do I go back to that configuration screen to change my option?

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration screen"? Sounds like an OS tool. For example, Debian has dpkg-reconfigure, and I know it has some sort of graphical configuration for first time email setup

Comment: I'm actually using `exim` now, to launch the configuration screen after installing exim is `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`.  I was looking for something similar for postfix.

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure postfix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The postfix configuration is stored in /etc/postfix/main.cf and /etc/postfix/master.cf.  You can change the options there and restart postfix.  If you are going to be running a postfix server, you will want to become at least a little familiar with these two files (especially main.cf).  The options are well documented at postfix.org.

As a tip, something I like to do is make a backup of main.cf then go through and delete everything that is commented out.  That way I have less crap to sort through when I need to modify it and it makes it a little less overwhelming.

Comment: the "postconf" command is also helpful, especially to show parameters which are defaults, but not defined in the main.cf configuration file

Answer (score 26):

The comment by [derchris](https://serverfault.com/users/75154/derchris) above is the actual answer to the original question. I know it's been years since this was asked, but neither of the answers were actually specific to the original question.

So to be clear, to get back to the configuration screen for postfix installation do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

The `dpkg-reconfigure` command is useful for other packages that have configuration screens during the startup process as well.

Answer (score 15):

After adjusting configuration as Alex describes use:

```
postconf
```

(As malcom commented above) To verify that the configuration file is reasonably correct and list all configurations actually applied, then:

```
sudo postfix check
```

To verify again that the configuration file is reasonably correct and create any necessary directories.
Then use:

```
sudo postfix reload
```

To apply the updated configuration.